# Ignore certain files when exporting APK with Eclipse ADT

Tags: android, cordova, eclipse-adt

Is there a way in Eclipse ADT to ignore a certain set of files under the Package Explorer when exporting an APK package?

I have a PhoneGap application that reuses a whole bunch of js/css/images with another application, but currently the APK export is including **everything** under my "assets" directory, inflating the APK size as a result. Ideally, I only want certain js/css/image files under my "assets" directory to be included in the package instead of everything.

Comment: I have the same question, I want to exclude some .js unit test files in a folder /assets/www/test from the apk build but want to keep them there for convenience.

Comment: My current workaround is to use symlinks (Yes, Windows has them too!) to only include the files I'm interested in. Not a true solution though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is any support in the SDK/API to achieve this directly but you put your shared resources into a directory on to the memory card and refer to them there from your app? Though your next question is how would you 'install' the shared images etc without including them in the .apk file.. which I'm not sure of the answer.